# Response generates TypeError just on Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using Ajax to get a response and cache some selectors depending of the device ID to manipulate then during the execution of the page as follows:

```
$updateRate = 300000;
$devices_temperature_integer = []
$devices_temperature_decimal = []
$devices_humidity = []
$devices_luminosity = []
$devices_atm_pressure = []

$(".monitoring.weather_monitoring").ready(function() {
  cacheInfo();
  getInfo();

  $allTimer = setInterval(
    function() {
      getInfo();
    },
    $updateRate
  );
  return false;
});

function cacheInfo() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/get_all_current_weather_infos",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $devices_temperature_integer[i] = $('#device-'+response[i][0].id+"-temperature-integer");
        $devices_temperature_decimal[i] = $('#device-'+response[i][0].id+"-temperature-decimal");
        $devices_humidity[i] = $('#device-'+response[i][0].id+"-humidity");
        $devices_luminosity[i] = $('#device-'+response[i][0].id+"-luminosity-data");
        $devices_atm_pressure[i] = $('#device-'+response[i][0].id+"-atm_pressure");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}

function getInfo() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/get_all_current_weather_infos",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $temp = response[i][1].data.toFixed(1);
        $intPart = ($temp+"").split(".")[0];
        $decPart = ($temp+"").split(".")[1];
        $devices_temperature_integer[i].html($intPart)  //Error here
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

It is working smoothly on Chrome but I am getting `TypeError: $devices_temperature_integer[i] is undefined` (it is the first array that I am manipulating) on Safari and Firefox. Also, sometimes if I keep refreshing the page on these browsers, the error disappears and the page works. Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: I don't see you get `$devices_temperature_integer` from the response. So where does it come from?

Comment: @CRice, I fixed there.

Comment: Still, I don't see anywhere in your code where you initialize `$devices_temperature_integer`. Do you have a line somewhere that looks like `$devices_temperature_integer = []` that you've left out of the snippet?

Comment: @CRice Sorry, now I added the full code

Comment: Maybe the ajax request in `getInfo` finishes *before* the one from `cacheInfo`, so when the `getInfo` success function runs, the `$devices_temperature_integer` is still empty. If you `console.log($devices_temperature_integer.length)` inside the `getInfo` success callback, what does it show?

Comment: @CRice, when the page loads, it show "1", which would be the correct, but when the error shows up it shows "0".

Comment: @CRice you are right. One Ajax call was sometimes finishing before the other. I used `$.ajax({ ... }).done(getInfo)` and it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Ajax call was finished before the other that would give some parameters. So I used `$.ajax({ ... }).done(getInfo)` to prevent this to happen.